# How to write an HQL query that to handle optional input parameters

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

```
 @Query("SELECT c FROM message c" 
       +" WHERE (CASE WHEN a=''    THEN 1=1 ELSE a= :a"
       + "           WHEN b=''     THEN 1=1 ELSE b= :b"
       + "           WHEN c=''     THEN 1=1 ELSE c= :c"
       + "           WHEN d=''     THEN 1=1 ELSE d= :d)")
```

I am trying to write an HQL query that has *optional* inputs of values a, b, c, and d.

My goal is to have the query recognize if an input =' 'and then just move along with 1=1 essentially doing nothing.

I keep getting error
*antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected token: =*

First the error token was "CASE" and now it is "=".

Is the "1=1 approach" viable?
Can I use CASE statements like this in HQL?

Thank you

UPDATED ATTEMPT:

```
 @Query("SELECT c "
               + "FROM message c" 
               + " WHERE"
               + " CASE (WHEN a != '' THEN a = :a"
               + "    WHEN b != ''   THEN b = :b"
               + "    WHEN c != ''   THEN c = :c"
               + "    WHEN d != ''   THEN d = :d)"

antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected token: WHEN
antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected token: a
antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected token: THEN
```

Comment: YES you can but why don't you just use `WHEN b!=''  THEN b= :b`

Comment: I can make that change, thank you. Any idea why I am getting antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected token: =

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that You want to use JPQL to do this operation?
I would suggest you to use [`Query By Example`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/jpa/query-by-example) OR [`QueryDSL`](https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/)

If you want to continue using `JPQL`, then Read ahead :P

You can use `sPEL` inside `@Query` if you want to use conditional operator. Here is a sample query based on your requirement.

```
@Query("SELECT C FROM Message C " +
       "WHERE 1=1 " +
       "AND ((1=:#{ #param1 == null ? 1 : 0 }) OR (C.param1 = :#{#param1})) " +
       "AND ((1=:#{ #param2 == null ? 1 : 0 }) OR (C.param2 = :#{#param2})) " +
       "AND ((1=:#{ #param3 == null ? 1 : 0 }) OR (C.param3 = :#{#param3})) " +
       "AND ((1=:#{ #param4 == null ? 1 : 0 }) OR (C.param4 = :#{#param4})) "
)
List<Message> find(@Param("param1") Long param1, @Param("param2") Long param2,@Param("param3") Long param3, @Param("param4") Long param4);
```

**A Little Explanation**

1. First Condition `1=1`: Hehe, obsessed with conditions on next line to `WHERE` clause, you can remove it.
2. `((1=:#{ #param1 == null ? 1 : 0 }) OR (C.param1 = :#{#param1}))`: Crazzy !!
   First part will decide whether to check second part or not. Suppose param1 is `null` then `(1=:#{ #param1 == null ? 1 : 0 })` will return `1=1` and `(C.param1 = :#{#param1})` will be skipped.
3. Same will apply to further conditions.

Feel free to comment, if you have any doubts.

BTW, you should use fields with respect to the object inside JPQL. For example `C.param1` instead of just `param1`.